# SystemOpen Excel with a startup switch

Tags: run

Hi i want to system open excel but with a parameter `"/e"`.

`SystemOpen["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.exe"]` works but there is no way to pass the parameter `"/e"` to the excel executable.

Comment: Try using `Run` instead.

Comment: `Run["start \"Excel\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.exe\" /e"]` works but in the next line if i call `Needs["ExcelLink"];ExcelOpen[workbookPath];` i get the error Excel is not open. So the process running using the `Run` command somehow is not visible globally but Excel opened using `SystemOpen` is accessible by `ExcelLink` package.

Comment: Try ``Run["start \"Excel\"]`` then try using `ExcelLink`. The `/e` switch might be the problem.